# External HDD not showing

Tags: external-hdd

Until now my Seagate 1TB external HDD was working perfectly. All of sudden, neither light on the HDD is blinking nor it is being displayed (I can feel the rev's if I put my hand on HDD though).
 I tried mounting it through cmd line by using these commands.

`sudo mkdir /media/External-HDD
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g -y
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/External-HDD`

It gave the below error.

Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.

What might have gone wrong? It's a new hard disk, not even a year old

[image]

Comment: Based on the image is not recognizing the format as NTFS, the safest is to connect it to a windows machine and try first to fix it there. If nothing on windows work, i wil [try ntfsfix](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ntfs-partition-repair-and-recovery-in-linux/)

Comment: I connected in windows, still light doesn't blink neither it is getting connected

Comment: on trying ntfsfix it is saying  it gave following error : Mounting volume... Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Input/output error
Error reading bootsector: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.

Comment: on trying fsck it got the following error : fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb
Could this be a zero-length partition?

Comment: so your partition seems to be messed up, before doing anything else i will try a recovery software like `photored` on linux. This one it's efective but doesn't preserve the original filenames so it's messy. I knew that on windoes there are a few that preserve file structure and names.